# PHP Time String Difference

Tags: php, string, date, time

I need help with my brand new experience with PHP coding!

I have two time **strings** with the following format:

```
hh:mm:ss yyyy-mm-dd
```

find two examples down below:

```
10:35:56 2013-11-15
11:46:24 2013-11-16
```

I need to get the difference between the second and the first one (using some PHP function or line of code) in some way that could be reused to compute the same difference of other rows in my DB on demand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start=strtotime("10:35:56 2013-11-15");
$end=strtotime("11:46:24 2013-11-16");
$difference=$end-$start;
echo $difference. " Seconds";
```

Answer (score 2):

use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date1 = strtotime('10:35:56 2013-11-15');
$date2 = strtotime('11:46:24 2013-11-16');

echo $date2 - $date1 . 'seconds';
```

Comment: Just like mine was, this answer is wrong. strtotime is not recognizing that format correctly. Run a fiddle

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky really? `strtotime('11:46:24 2013-11-16') = 1384602384` which is correct, `strtotime('10:35:56 2013-11-15') = 1384511756` which is correct

Comment: http://codepad.org/aQHDbDel   The difference using your and my code is 90628 seconds. Do you think there are so many seconds in one day?

Comment: `86400seconds` in a day + `3600seconds` in 1 hour + `600seconds` in 10minutes + `28seconds`

Comment: Sorry, its embarrassing but I don't know what I was thinking. This answer is correct.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky go home math, you're drunk ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way with `strtotime` :

```
$date1 = strtotime("10:35:56 2013-11-15");
$date2 = strtotime("11:46:24 2013-11-16");
$date_diff = $date2 - $date1; // here you got difference in seconds.
echo $date_diff . " seconds";
```

Or with `DateTime` object :

```
$datetime1 = date_create('10:35:56 2013-11-15');
$datetime2 = date_create('11:46:24 2013-11-16');
$date_diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $date_diff ->format('%s seconds');
```

The `$date_diff -> format(...)` uses [this list of format.](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/dateinterval.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

For exact difference try this

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('10:35:56 2013-11-15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('11:46:24 2013-11-16');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds <br/>";
```